# tensorflow error Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

Error when checking input: expected `flatten_input` to have shape `(28, 28)` but got array with shape `(28, 3)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ4TS.png)

I am trying to compare single image with starter tensorflow project whıch ıs avaılable on tensorflow begınner MNIST

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: why.....fffdsfds

Answer (score 0):

Your `Flatten` layer is taking an array of 28x3, but it expects a 28x28 array. Maybe the logic is that your layer is taking a 28x28 pixel image as a 28x28 array, but your data has the shape of 28x3. You need to turn your input array into a 28x28 array. Instead, you can try to change the first layer `input_shape` into `(28, 3)`.

**EDIT:**

You have two problems in your code. First, analyze this line of code:

```py
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
```

Here you are expecting an input of 28x28 monochromatic image array (black and white). So, for this, i've did the next using `cv2`:

```py
img = cv2.imread("./image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
```

Before, your image has a shape of 28x28x3 (where 3 is the RGB channel). Using `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` we got a 28x28 with a monochromatic channel. However, we need to divide every pixel value by 255.0 to get each value between 0 and 1.

```py
img = img/255.0
```

In my case, `image.png` is a white background handwritten digit. To make this more accurate, i've inverted colors.

Now you got a well formatted predict data. But there is one more problem.

```py
result = model.predict_classes(img)
```

As you saw with `model.layers[0].input_shape`, your `Flatten` layer wants a (None, 28, 28) parameter. That `None` is the number of members of your dataset. If you check `x_train.shape`, you will get (60000, 28, 28) where the first number is the size of the dataset.

Well, to solve that you just need to do the next:

```py
result = model.predict_classes(img.reshape(1, 28, 28))
```

Now it works.

Comment: i have resized the image to 28x28, how can ıt say 28x3

Comment: model(None, 28, 28)
np.asarray result (360, 260, 3)

Comment: Your dataset data is a matrix of 28x28 with numbers between 0 and 1. The problem with your image is that you've not converted it into an array of 28x28 with monochromatic values. The problem is that your image is using three RGB channels.

Comment: i have converted it to grayscaleö thats ok but now result is like [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] and other test_x[20] (which is 9) result is [[5.2455994e-07 1.1379902e-05 1.9626364e-07 4.2499753e-04 7.6113723e-04
  8.6696427e-06 1.1180204e-11 4.4427094e-01 1.3968789e-04 5.5438250e-01]]

Comment: That's the reliability number of each digit. You can see ten numbers in that array.

Comment: yes but thats wrong input number 3 returns 6 ,, also test db number background is white and number black but my images bg is black and number is white i created white backgrounded number image for custom input

Comment: Note that the used layer architecture is not the recommended to classify images. It is used for practical and first learning cases. If you want to be more accurate with new items, you need to search about Convolutional Neural Networks, who are designed to classify images.

Comment: The layer architecture is every layer in your model. Search about LeNet architecture. That was made by one of the MNIST creators and is easy to understand.

Comment: how can this read all sequental handwriting ,not only single letter we need word

Comment: This implementation can't achieve that with accuracy. You need more complex architectures like VGG-19, which uses convolutional layers to achieve his objective. Check this journal project http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/810.pdf